# How to show old sent emails on Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I am trying out Thunderbird as a new email client.

Until now it works fine except I have no "sent" folder! I have emails I sent with my previous client that I need to see, which are not showing up in Thunderbird. I managed to make appear the "sent" folder by sending an email, but now the folder contains only that one email.

Is there a way to retrieve all previously sent emails on Thunderbird?

Comment: It depends. How are you accessing your mail account, POP3 or IMAP? Can you access your mail account on the web?

Comment: I can access the mail account via the web where I can see all my sent emails.
As for the server type I am using IMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you need to subscribe to your Sent Items folder.

In the accountlist, right-click the email address. (not Inbox or any other folder, the actual email address (or name of your mailbox if its not the email address).

From here, click Subscribe.

[image]

Find the Send Items folder, ensure it is checked, and hit Subscribe at the right. If you see multiple Send Items, just subscribe to all of them. In the worst case, you'll download some empty folders.

[image]

After you hit okay, the folders will appear and you can navigate to them.

You can now also change the default Sent Items folder in thunderbird to that new folder to ensure that it is synchronised between Thunderbird and your webmail.

Comment: Amazing! You saved my day! The sent folder of my account was called "sent items" and for that reason Thunderbird wasn't happy. I also had to change the settings for "copies and folders".

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as solved, so others know you no longer need help. :)